# ST-Link no connect

Tags: embedded, stm32, nucleo

I've made a mistake and programmed to STM32h745 dual core processor program which was created to STM32H743 with one core. Now I have a problem with connection and ST-Link doesn't recognize device.
What can I do with that?

Comment: Did you try connect under reset? :)

Comment: yes, I have tried it in st-link utility and with the button.

Comment: I can try also to pull down NRST pin to GND and then erase chip. Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: Yes :) You can try. Check datasheet what for NRST pin is :)

Comment: Ihave tried to supply with the reset (NRSt pulled down to GND) and I get fail "The interface firmware FAILED to reset/halt the target MCU"

Comment: Does your connection with MCU support using BOOT0 pin?

Answer (score 0):

When connectiong cycle reset button. You can find a moment when the bad firmware still is not reprogrammed IO-s and ST-LINK than can stop the core.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pulling up BOOT1 to 3V3, connecting to supply and clearing the memory of CPU. But unexpectedly it turns out that it was caused by programming the wrong soft by it happend always after programming the soft generated by CubeMX. I don't know what is wrong with that